# Hierarchical taxonomy breadcrumb

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, breadcrumbs

I have a view that displays terms hierarchically via a view attachment, but neither the URL nor the breadcrumb keep track of where it is in the hierarchy. For example, a taxonomy structured like the following.

- Category

  - Term I

    - Term A

      - Term 1
  - Term II

    - Term B

It displays a page listing Term I and Term II. Upon clicking on *Term I*, the user is taken to the page for *Term A*, which is a list of its sub-terms (*Term 1*). Upon clicking, the user is taken to a list of nodes tagged with that therm.

The path and breadcrumb for each of these pages is, sequentially, the following.

- /category
- /category/term-i
- /category/term-a
- /category/term-1

I would like instead for the breadcrumb and path to be the following.

- /category
- /category/term-i
- /category/term-i/term-a
- /category/term-i/term-a/term-1

I've tried the [Hansel](http://drupal.org/project/hansel) and [Custom Breadcrumbs](http://drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs) modules, but I have been unable to configure them properly, or they just don't provide the functionality I need.

I'm using Drupal 7 with a theme based on [Omega](http://drupal.org/project/omega/), so any answer that include instructions to insert code into template or other theme files need to include information about where that code belongs in Omega.

Answer (score 2):

These are two separate questions. One about the path, another about the breadcrumb.

**Breadcrumbs:**

Disclaimer: The solution presented here may need more tweaking, if your taxonomy/term/% is replaced by a views page with contextual filter. (I never do that, there are other ways to achieve the same)

[Crumbs](http://drupal.org/project/crumbs) will do the trick. 90% of the task out of the box. If not, check this doc: http://drupal.org/node/1984484

You need some manual work to make "/category" the top-level breadcrumb item for all the terms: (this explanation is for the 7.x-2.x branch)
Visit Admin > Structure > Crumbs > Entity parent > Taxonomy
Set 'category' as the parent path for your vocabulary.
Go back to Admin > Structure > Crumbs
Move crumbs.entityParent.* into the "Enabled" section, and give it a low enough priority.

**Path:**

I suppose you have [pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) installed already.
Go to Admin > Configuration > Search and metadata > URL aliases
Look at "Taxonomy term paths".

I read somewhere that the following pattern will do the trick:

```
category/[term:parents:join-path]/[term:name]
```

Not tested myself. Good luck with it :)